# Compile error on one Android Studio, not other

Tags: android, compilation

Relative newbie here... At home, my program ran nicely.

I brought computer to work and got the following when I opened it up to work on it:

> An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_40). Please file a
>   bug at the Java Developer Connection
>   (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade
>   for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in
>   your report.  Thank you.
>
> ```
> java.lang.ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag 185 in class file com/sun/tools/javac/tree/JCTree$JCCompilationUnit
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)com/sun/tools/javac/tree/JCTree$JCCompilationUnit
> ```

... "`Unknown constant tag`" as keywords haven't yielded other answers. "`compiler error`" questions like it don't have answers.

When I tried the same program in my office computer, it runs fine. I'm probably an update behind on that.   It will run on my device as well as the emulator.

I can post the other many lines of the error message ... but I'd like to know if this is something that is likely to go away with the next update, whether I should try to figure out how to submit a bug, or whether a typo in my code (say, the name of a string not following the naming rules) would generate this kind of error.   (If this is not an appropriate "question" please advise.)

Thanks for input & suggestions.

Comment: Try these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12333849/classformaterror-unknown-constant-tag-in-class-xy , and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330192/how-to-fix-unknown-constant-tag-32-in-class-file-com-sun-org-apache-xerces-inte?rq=1 . Hope you get some helpful info.

Comment: With no changes it worked early this a.m.   I'm going to comb carefully through my arrays and arrayLists to make sure everything's kosher and hope for the best.  Thanks for the edit, too.