# Not able to launch Jmeter 3.1 due to error Unknown constant tag 204 in class file javax/swing /RepaintManager errorlevel=1

Tags: jmeter

Getting an error as when tried to launch Jmeter 3.1

```
An error occurred: Unknown constant tag 204 in class file javax/swing  /RepaintManager
```

errorlevel=1

i was running 100 users test in my local system (RAM is 16GB) and stopped the test in between of execution, after that facing this issue. Please suggest.

Jmeter log:

```
2017/08/21 14:33:14 FATAL - jmeter.JMeter: An error occurred:  java.lang.ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag 204 in class file javax/swing/RepaintManager
at javax.swing.UIManager.initialize(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.UIManager.maybeInitialize(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar.getAllLAFs(JMeterMenuBar.java:678)
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.LookAndFeelCommand.<clinit>(LookAndFeelCommand.java:58)
at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startGui(JMeter.java:315)
at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:483)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:259)
```

Comment: Thanks for guiding. I will uninstall Java and try to launch Jmeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JVM is most probably corrupt, see:

- [How to fix: Unknown constant tag 32 in class file com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/impl/xs/XMLSchemaValidator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330192/how-to-fix-unknown-constant-tag-32-in-class-file-com-sun-org-apache-xerces-inte)

Reinstall the JDK for it 7 or 8 (advised).

I would also advise you to upgrade to last JMeter 3.2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @UBIK LOAD PACK for help and guidance. After restarting the system (2 times, one time system got restarted automatically by showing error code: Memory management issue), able to launch Jmeter 3.1 successfully.